# Is the WAI-ARIA role="radiogroup" wrong, when autosubmitting on selection

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

**Background:**

I am brushing up accessibility in [this application](https://h5p.org/single-choice-set).

The user must select one of the supplied answers to a question. The answers can be navigated between using the arrow keys on the keyboard.

When the user presses space or enter, the choice is made, and a new set of questions appear.

**My question to stack overflow:**

Is `role="radiogroup"` and `role="radio"` incorrect to use here, since it autosubmits and moves to the next question set?

Does `radiogroup` imply that the user would be able to change their answer before pressing a submit button?

If yes, what would be a better way, to indicate to a read speaker what this is?

Comment: It might help to have context for why you are not using radio buttons (styled to look like bars). Sometimes knowing what about a standard control does not work makes it easier to understand if assigning that role to a new control is appropriate or should be something else.